# tikz externalization and multiple axis using \ref and \label for legendentry

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing, tikz-external, legend

I have a plot consisting of two y-axis. When I'm adding the legendentries in each axis environment, the first legendentry will be plotted "behind" the plot of the second axis. Thus I thought a solution might be the \ref \label to plot both legendentries at the end of the document, that they will appear in the very front of all plots and not hidden.
Unfortunately using the tikz externalization gives the error "undefined references ...." and the legendentries are given with "??" only.
I checked the manual for using \legend \ref with externalization, but it doesn't help. I tried to compile several times.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,openright,oneside,DIV11,a4paper,numbers=noenddot,headsepline,parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[shapes.arrows]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

% set up externalization
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                legend cell align=left,
            bar width=7pt,
            xmin=-3, xmax=30,
            axis y line*=left,
            xlabel=Laser current / \si{\milli\ampere},
            ylabel=Tuning range / \si{\nano\metre},
            nodes near coords align=left,
            nodes near coords,]
        \addplot[ybar, ybar legend, draw=gray, fill=gray, color=gray] table[x=current,y=tuning] {Tun_SMSR.txt};

%          \addlegendentry{Abstimmbereich};
       \label{Abstimmbereich};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
            every axis legend/.append style={fill=white, anchor=north west, at={(0.35,0.18)}},
            legend cell align=left,
            ybar=5pt,
            ybar interval=0.6,
            bar width=7pt,
            xmin=-3, xmax=30,
            ymin=30, ymax=60,
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line=none,
            ylabel=SMSR / \si{\deci\bel},
            nodes near coords align=left,
            nodes near coords,]
        \addplot[ybar, ybar legend, draw=black, color=black] table[x=current,y=SMSR] {Tun_SMSR.txt};
       \label{SMSR};
%          \addlegendentry{SMSR};

    \end{axis}

\node [draw,fill=white] at (rel axis cs: 0.7,0.15) {\shortstack[l]{
\ref{Abstimmbereich} Abstimmbereich\\
\ref{SMSR} SMSR
}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with the command

```
lualatex -shell-escape "document name".tex
```

The resulting figure shows the legends but with no symbols and "??" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to a label which has been externalized to a separate pdf - which is a complex task.

Here, "complex" means "too complex for the standard -shell-escape image externalization". In order to reference something inside of some external image, you have to take special steps.

To quote from the pgfplots manual: "For point a), a `\ref` inside of an externalized graphics works only if you issue the required system call
manually or by make. The initial configuration `mode=convert with system call`does not support
`\ref`. But you can copy­paste the system call generated by `mode=convert with system call` and
issue it manually. The reason is that `\ref` information is stored in the main `.aux` file ­ but this
auxiliary file is not completely written when `mode=convert with system call` is invoked (there is a
race condition). Note that `\pageref` is not supported (sorry). Thus: if you have `\ref` inside of external
graphics, consider using `mode=list and make` or copy­paste the system call for the image(s) and issue
it manually."

Alternatively, you can wait (say) one week until the next version of pgfplots is released. It supports layered graphics such that the first legend will not appear behind the second axis.

Another altivernative solution might be to insert a legend entry for the first plot into the legend of the second image using `\addlegendimage{<style>}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        plot 0/.style={
            ybar, ybar legend, draw=gray, fill=gray, color=gray
        }
    }
       \begin{axis}[
                legend cell align=left,
            bar width=7pt,
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            axis y line*=left,
            xlabel=Laser current,
            ylabel=Tuning range,
            nodes near coords align=left,
            nodes near coords,]
        \addplot[plot 0] {rand};

%          \addlegendentry{Abstimmbereich};
 %      \label{Abstimmbereich};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
            every axis legend/.append style={fill=white, anchor=north west, at={(0.35,0.18)}},
            legend cell align=left,
            ybar=5pt,
            ybar interval=0.6,
            bar width=7pt,
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            ymin=30, ymax=60,
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line=none,
            ylabel=SMSR,
            nodes near coords align=left,
            nodes near coords,]

\addlegendentry{Abstimmbereich}
\addlegendimage{plot 0}
        \addplot[ybar, ybar legend, draw=black, color=black] {30 + rand*30};
       \label{SMSR};
          \addlegendentry{SMSR};

    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have deliberately stripped the example from your data files and some other stuff - the only point here is the special legend construction. 
This does also work with image externalization.

In order to share the common options, I extracted the style for your first plot and used it at two places (this has the same effect as `\label{Abstimmbereich}` and `refstyle={Abstimmbereich}`, but it integrates seamlessly into the image externalization workflow).

Comment: Hi Christian, this was what I read in the manual as well, but I didn't get the point what it means by "making it manually". I found out that I have to set up the lualatex first with:
lualatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "filename-figure0" "\def \tikzexternalrealjob {filename}\input {filename}"

and removed: 

\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape ...

from the tex-document.Then I compiled with:

lualatex -shell-escape filename.tex

and the figure looks now as I want it to look like. I Guess thats what the manual is saying by manually?

Comment: Ah, not quite. "make it manually" means that you have to open a windows command prompt (or linux shell) and type the command `lualatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "filename-figure0" "\def \tikzexternalrealjob {filename}\input {filename}"`

Comment: Also see my edit: I added a fully working example which relies on `\addlegendimage` and avoids all problems of image externalization.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I used the command prompt. Thanks for your help!