# How to refer to pgfplot legend labels with hyperref?

Tags: pgfplots, hyperref, labels, tikz-external, multiple-files

I would like to `\ref`er to a pgf legend label in the caption of a figure (to explain symbols). I create my figures with externalization. Without the `hyperref` package, everything works fine. But as soon as I include `hyperref`, errors emerge.

First of all, using `\caption{\ref{figurelegend}}` gives me an error.
`Paragraph endet before \Hy@setref@link was complete...`
Apparently, hyperlinking does not work. But I have already expected this behavior since the aux file created by the externalization does not include hyperref information.

As a next approach I tried disabling the hyperref for this link using `\caption{\ref*{figurelegend}}`. However, this gives me an error.
`Exta \else ...` which I can not understand at all.

So I thought, maybe `\protect`ing the reference would help. Unfortunately, `\caption{\protect\ref*{figurelegend}}` gives me the same error.

I also tried `\pgfplotslegendfromname{figurelegend}`. It compiles without errors but I only produces "??". Somehow the aux file from the externalization seems to be invisible for this command.

Again I emphasize that without `hyperref`, everything works fine. **So how can I properly refer to pgf legend labels from externalizeded figures when hyperref is activated?**

Here is a **minimal working example**:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref,graphicx,tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % remove comment to break everything

\makeatletter\write\@auxout{\string\@input{figure.aux}}\makeatother % include the externalized references

\begin{document}
\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig.pdf} 
  \caption{Here is a red line: \ref{figurelegend}}
\end{figure}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

`figure.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[force remake=true,figure list=true,mode=list and make]

\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{fig}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
    \addplot[red,domain=1:2] {x^2}; \addlegendentry{$x^2$}; \label{figurelegend}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To compile, evoke

```
pdflatex figure
make -f figure.makefile
pdflatex main
```

**Related links** which might prove useful for someone else:

1. [How to use refer to pgf legend labels when using externalization.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67512/tikz-externalization-and-multiple-axis-using-ref-and-label-for-legendentry?rq=1)
2. [A simple workaround (which I can not use due to memory issues) is to disable externalization for the figure of interest.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179098/pgfplots-externalize-with-hyperref?rq=1)

Comment: Would you be so kind to add an MWE.

Comment: Its kind of difficult, but I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `standalone` instead of `externalize` (which has the advantage of being far more efficient as well).

```
\documentclass[multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
    \addplot[red,domain=1:2] {x^2}; \addlegendentry{$x^2$}; \label{figurelegend}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{figurelegend}
\end{document}
```

which in this case produces file `test.pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,page=1]{test.pdf} 
  \caption{Here is a red line: \protect\includegraphics[page=2]{test.pdf}}
\end{figure}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped page]

Comment: This works fine, although, it somehow seems like a cumbersome workaround.